# Replace url that contains a unique id

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, replace

I am trying to write sql to replace sql fields anywhere a certain url occurs with a new url. The problem is part of the url contains a unique id with I need to replace too.

E.g. the field content contains the following:

```
<ul><li><a href="http://domain1/d/d/workspace/SpacesStore/c83b1d75-46e0-11df-9ce1-e95be40e0484/identity.pdf">Identity Verification</a></li>
<li><a href="http://domain1/d/d/workspace/SpacesStore/57c7311a-648a-11de-854d-5fc4c5292a7d/PersonalData.pdf">Personal Data</a></li>
<li><a href="http://domain1/d/d/workspace/SpacesStore/68abe041-e0f4-11de-ba27-4fe2c6117213/ProfessionalChecks.pdf">Professional Check</a></li></ul>
```

when updated I would like it to become:

```
<ul><li><a href="http://domain2/identity.pdf">Identity Verification</a></li>
<li><a href="http://domain2/PersonalData.pdf">Personal Data</a></li>
<li><a href="http://domain2/ProfessionalChecks.pdf">Professional Check</a></li></ul>
```

I need to replace all the first part of the url up to the document name with http://domain2/ but this needs to be done for each of the urls and they all contain unique strings. Is there anyway to do this using the replace function ?

ie.

```
Update Table 
set content = replace(content, url,newurl)
where content like '%http://domain1/d/d/workspace/SpacesStore/%'
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also specify what the output should be.  It is not clear what you mean by "document name" in the URL.

Comment: You can use some clever `substring` technique, possibly search for last `/` and replace all that precedes it

Comment: thanks Gordon for the tips ! I have updated it now.